# How to Replace CodeMirror with TinyMCE in wordpress code editor without plugin?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, codemirror

how to convert wordpress post/page source code editor (just html) to built in wordpress's codemirror with code?

i think the first step is dequeue tinymce and add wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror'); or something like add a plugin to tinymce for highlighting html css syntax...

Answer (score 1):

my best practice is this code:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'codemirror_test_que_code_editor');
function codemirror_test_que_code_editor()
{
    wp_enqueue_code_editor(array(
        'type'       => 'htmlmixed',
    ));
    wp_add_inline_script('code-editor', '
            jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
               wp.codeEditor.initialize( jQuery( \'[id="content"]\' ) );
            });');
}
```